# How many SVN checkouts of my project on google code?

Tags: svn, statistics, google-code, checkout

My project uses Google Code. Is there a way to find out how many checkouts there have been?

Comment: FYI, this question was asked on Stack Overflow with no answers either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100249/any-way-to-know-how-many-checkouts-of-my-code-have-happened-from-code-google-com

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804970/is-there-a-subversion-checkout-hook-or-something-similar)

Comment: I would have had to install that at the start, so its too late now. Also, I'm not clear that that I can use install hooks on Google Code?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it, unless you/Google had a script running to count this. A standard SVN server does not keep track of working copies or exports, and focuses purely on keeping the repository organised. I can't see how you could get this data unless it was recorded as it happened.